# Retrieve $_POST value from submit button

Tags: php, forms

I have a front end form and want to retrieve user input vale using `$_POST` in a variable. I had found similar threads here, but none of it couldn't solve my problem.

After accepting the variable in `$data`, I tried to print using `echo $data`. Nothing is shown. (But when I use other form input such as drop down or check box, `$data` contains data. I require the button type as mentioned here and wont be able to change).

HTML Form

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test_general.php" method="post" >    
            <input type="submit"  name="btn" value="but1">text1</button>
            <button type="submit" name="btn" value="but2">text2</button>    
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

PHP processing code

```
<html>
    <?php
        $data = $_POST['value'];
        echo $data;
    ?>
<html>
```

Comment: The post key should be the value of the name attribute `value` !== `btn`

Comment: You are opening an `<input>` tag, but closing it as a `<button>` tag. That's not correct.

Comment: There's two problems, 1) duplicate names, 2) incorrect tag ending for `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the post value `btn`. The name of the element is the key of the post value you want.

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['btn'];
    echo $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test_general.php" method="post" >    
<input type="text"  name="text" value="but1" placeholder="text1" />
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="but2">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will only show you what was filled in after clicking the submit button.

```
<html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
  $data = $_POST['text'];
  echo $data;
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked...!! As suggested, i changed into $_POST['btn']...

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons have the same name "btn". Try changing one of them and then read it on postback as $_POST['btn']

Comment: He needs to know which button has been clicked, so having the same name is correct because `$_POST['btn']` will contain `but1` or `but2`.